# splitting a string into a 3d array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, arduino

let's say that we have a string `str`:

```
String str = "1,2,3,4444444444;5,6,7,8888888888;.9,10,11,1212121212;.";
```

defining three dimensions `d1`, `d2` and `d3` that are embedded in the string as follow:

- `d1` has elements that are separated by a dot "."
- `d2` has elements that are separated by a semicolon ";"
- `d3` has elements that are separated by a comma ","

`d3` is a child of `d2` and `d2` is a child of `d1` (parent). `d1 > d2 > d3`.

we wish to have access to every element embedded in the string, meaning that we should have -as a result- an array as follows:

```
d[0][0][0] = "1";
d[0][0][1] = "2";
d[0][0][2] = "3";
d[0][0][3] = "4444444444";
d[0][1][0] = "5";
d[0][1][1] = "6";
d[0][1][2] = "7";
d[0][1][3] = "8888888888";
d[1][0][0] = "9";
d[1][0][1] = "10";
d[1][0][2] = "11";
d[1][0][3] = "12121212";
```

- you can see that `d[i][j][k]` where `k = [0, 2]` are integers.
- you can see that `d[i][j][k]` where `k = 3` are long integers.

we wish to convert these strings to their appropriate integer type now (either a regular integer or a long integer). meaning that our final array should look like this:

```
d[0][0][0] = 1; // int
d[0][0][1] = 2; // int
d[0][0][2] = 3; // int
d[0][0][3] = 4444444444; // long int
d[0][1][0] = 5; // int
d[0][1][1] = 6; // int
d[0][1][2] = 7; // int
d[0][1][3] = 8888888888; // long int
d[1][0][0] = 9; // int
d[1][0][1] = 10; // int
d[1][0][2] = 11; // int
d[1][0][3] = 12121212; // long int
```

this idea is to be implemented on an arduino microcontroller, which is c/c++ based.

here is my take on it, not working properly unfortunately.

```
  String data = "1,2,3,1445303228;4,5,6,1445303228;.7,8,9,1445303273;.";

  int data_length = data.length() + 1;

  if (data_length != 1) {

    char d0[data_length]; // couldn't do it with String, let's try char
    data.toCharArray(d0, data_length);

    int size1 = 32, size2 = 64; // intuitive sizes

    char d1[size1][136]; // strlen("1,2,3,1445303228") * 8, 17 * 8 = 136

    int i = 0;
    for (char *p = strtok(d0, "."); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, "."))
    strcpy(d1[i++], p); // d1

    int d1_length = i;

    char d2[d1_length][size2][17]; // strlen("1,2,3,1445303228") = 16

    int d2_length[size2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) d2_length[i] = 0; // initialize array = 0

    for (int i = 0; i < d1_length; i++) {
      int j = 0;
      for (char *p = strtok(d1[i], ";"); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, ";"))
      strcpy(d2[i][j++], p); // d2

      d2_length[i] = j;
    }

    int d2_length_max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
    if (d2_length[i] > d2_length_max) d2_length_max = d2_length[i];

    char d3[d1_length][d2_length_max][4][10];
    // d2 can have 4 d3's max, d3 can have 10 chars max

    for (int i = 0; i < d1_length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < d2_length[i]; j++) {
        int k = 0;
        for (char *p = strtok(d2[i][j], ","); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, ","))
        strcpy(d3[i][j][k++], p); // d3
      }
    }

    int rows[d1_length][d2_length_max][3];
    long rows_long[d1_length][d2_length_max];

    for (int i = 0; i < d1_length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < d2_length[i]; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    rows[i][j][k] = atoi(d3[i][j][k]); // char array to integer

    for (int i = 0; i < d1_length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < d2_length[i]; j++) {
      char temp[10];
      for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) temp[k] = d3[i][j][3][k];
      rows_long[i][j] = atol(temp); // char array to long
    }

  }
```

please note that the long integer is infact a unix timestamp.

Comment: Do you know the size before parsing ? Have you tried something ?

Comment: Do you know the number of elements and the size before parsing?

Comment: @Ôrel i don't know the size before parsing, we cannot tell, that's part of the trick actually, it depends on the size of the string which can vary. i have posted my attempt below.

Comment: @Magisch the generated array size depends on the length of the string, which can vary, i am reading the string directly from a text file stored on a micro sd card, basically it will give me a string object `String str;`.

Comment: format is not consistent why have you a `;` before the `.` or why don't you have a `,` before the `;` and why do you have `;.` to finish the data ?

Comment: @Ôrel That's a really good call. I was wondering why it was so hard to get my regex to work. I didn't even recognize it till after you said something.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or in this case I'd recommend removing the code, as it demonstrates effort, but the architecture should unfortunately be simplified.

Comment: @Ôrel it is consistent my friend, they are separators `1,2,3,4444444444;5,6,7,8888888888;.9,10,11,1212121212;.`
becomes `1,2,3,4444444444;5,6,7,8888888888;` and  `9,10,11,1212121212;`, then they become `1,2,3,4444444444` and `5,6,7,8888888888` and `9,10,11,1212121212` and so on.

Comment: @JonathanMee i believe that the format of the string is valid, three delimiters, they will split the string into three parts. am i missing something?

Comment: No, it is not, you don't have a `,` after  `4444444444` in your example so you why have a `;` after `5,6,7,8888888888` ? Other way to show the pblm you have 3 `,` for 4 elements but 3 `;` for  3 elements

Comment: @Ôrel a parent `d1` can have any number of `d2` childs, they don't have to be equal. in this particular string we have `a` and `b`, `a` splits to `a0`, `a1`, while `b` splits to `b0` only.

Comment: @user5470921 If you have code that works I'd suggest posting that as an answer. And at a minimum you should only accept answers that actually answer the question. [milevyo's answer does not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33257838/2642059) if you are looking for C code [Ôrel's answer does answer the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33260205/2642059) and if you like C++ goodness my answer is viable.

Comment: @JonathanMee i'll do that, sure, you got a point. i am still in the middle of going through both of the solutions you mentioned, you see, i need to get these working on an arduino board chip, which is different from using a direct c/c++ compiler.

Comment: @user5470921 delimiter is to separate you don't put it a the end but between element. For example this string: `a00,a01,a02;a10,a11,a12.b00,b01,b02;b10,b11,b12` seems better than `a00,a01,a02;a10,a11,a12;.b00,b01,b02;b10,b11,b12;.`

Comment: @Ôrel i agree, it does seem better, and more logical for a human reader, the thing is that the string itself is generated with a set of loops, that's why we have some of delimiters appearing at the end, it shouldn't be a problem as long as we are aware and taking care of it, i am still in with you on having an appropriate style of where and how we should put the delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with a code that is mainly based on [@milevyo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33257838/5470921).

```
struct ds { int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0; long d = 0; };

struct data {
  struct ds array[32][8];
  int i, j[24];

  int n = 0, d1, d2, d3; char r[11];
  void get(String array) {
    if (array.length() + 1 != 1) {
      char buff[array.length() + 1];
      array.toCharArray(buff, array.length() + 1);
      char c; char *p = buff; int l;
      while (c = *p) {
        l = (c == ',') ? 1 : ((c == ';') ? 2 : ((c == '.') ? 3 : 0));
        if (l) a(l); else ch(c); p++;
      }
      a(l);
    }
  }
  void a(int l) {
    if (n) {
      if (d1 == 0) array[d3][d2].a = atoi(r);
      else if (d1 == 1) array[d3][d2].b = atoi(r);
      else if (d1 == 2) array[d3][d2].c = atoi(r);
      else if (d1 == 3) array[d3][d2].d = atol(r);
      i = d3 + 1; j[d3] = d2 + 1; n = 0;
    }
    switch (l) {
      case 3: d3++; d2 = d1 = 0; break;
      case 2: d2++; d1 = 0; break;
      case 1: d1++; break;
    }
  }
  void ch(char c) { r[n] = c; n++; r[n] = c = 0; }
} data;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(19200); 
  Serial.println(".."); 

  data.get("1,2,3,1445433855;4,5,6,1445433855;.7,8,9,1445438763;.");

  for (int i = 0; i < data.i; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data.j[i]; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        if (k == 0) Serial.print(data.array[i][j].a);
        else if (k == 1) Serial.print(data.array[i][j].b);
        else if (k == 2) Serial.print(data.array[i][j].c);
        else if (k == 3) Serial.print(data.array[i][j].d);
        Serial.print("\t");
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void loop () { }
```

from

```
1,2,3,1445433855;4,5,6,1445433855;.7,8,9,1445438763;.
```

to

```
..
1   2   3   1445433855  
4   5   6   1445433855  

7   8   9   1445438763
```

via

```
..
data.array[0][0].a  data.array[0][0].b  data.array[0][0].c  data.array[0][0].d
data.array[0][1].a  data.array[0][1].b  data.array[0][1].c  data.array[0][1].d

data.array[1][0].a  data.array[1][0].b  data.array[1][0].c  data.array[1][0].d
```

Answer (score 1):

With a dynamic flat array in pure C and then alloc the 3D array
The array size is double each time needed
You can set the first size with the define:

```
#define DEFAULT_SIZE 8
```

as said in my comment the format is strange `;.` should be `.` and the final `;.` should be removed

I add test to check if next line as the same size than the first one.

```
int main(void) { 
    char *data = "1,2,3,1445303228;4,5,6,1445303228;.7,8,9,1445303273;."; 
    char *p; 
    int size = DEFAULT_SIZE; 
    int nb_element = 0; 
    int s1 = 0; 
    int s2 = 0; 

    int cur1 = 0; 
    int cur2 = 0; 
    int cur3 = 0; 

    int *d = malloc(sizeof(int) * DEFAULT_SIZE); 
    int ***d3; 

    if (!d) { 
        return -1; 
    } 

    p = data; 
    while (*p) { 
        if (nb_element == size) { 
            size *= 2; 
            d = realloc(d, size * sizeof(int)); 
            if (!d) { 
                return -1; 
            } 
        } 
        d[nb_element++] = strtol(p, &p, 10); 
        switch (*p) { 
          case ',': 
            cur1++; 
            if (s1 && cur1 > s1) { 
                fprintf(stderr, "Too many element for %d, %d:" 
                        " get %d, expect %d\n", cur2, cur3, cur1, s1); 
                return -1; 
            } 
            break; 
          case ';': 
            cur1++; 
            cur2++; 
            if (s1 == 0) { 
                s1 = cur1; 
            } 
            cur1 = 0; 
            if (s2 && cur2 > s2) { 
                fprintf(stderr, "Too many element for %d:" 
                        " get %d, expect %d\n", cur3, cur2, s2); 
                return -1; 
            } 
            break; 
          case '.': 
          dot: 
            cur2++; 
            cur3++; 
            if (s2 == 0) { 
                s2 = cur2; 
            } 
            cur2 = 0; 
            cur1 = 0; 
            break; 
        } 
        p++; 
        /* XXX: ack due to strange format */ 
        if (*p == '.') 
            goto dot; 
    } 
    /*XXX! remove empty final line */ 
    cur3--; 

    d3 = malloc(sizeof(int **) * cur3); 
    for (int i = 0; i < cur3; i++) { 
        d3[i] = malloc(sizeof(int *) * s2); 
        for (int j = 0; j < s2; j++) { 
            d3[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int) * s1); 
            for (int k = 0; k < s1; k++) {  
                d3[i][j][k] = d[i * s2 + j * s1 + k]; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    free(d); 
    for (int i = 0; i < cur3; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < s2; j++) { 
            for (int k = 0; k < s1; k++) { 
                fprintf(stdout, "d[%d][%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j,k, d3[i][j][k]); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

output:

```
d[0][0][0] = 1
d[0][0][1] = 2
d[0][0][2] = 3
d[0][0][3] = 1445303228
d[0][1][0] = 4
d[0][1][1] = 5
d[0][1][2] = 6
d[0][1][3] = 1445303228
d[0][2][0] = 7
d[0][2][1] = 8
d[0][2][2] = 9
d[0][2][3] = 1445303273
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind upvoting a pure C solution, but it would need to put the values in a 3d array, not a 1d array that is indexed similarly to the 3d array.

Comment: Gotta say the `goto` is painful, but I have given the +1 as promised.

Comment: @JonathanMee I know the `goto` is painful, but I choose to write the parser for a correct syntax and highlight the ack to support the format error.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int c1,c2,c3;

int n=0;
char sResult[20];

void PrintLevel(int lvl){
    if(n){
        printf("d[%d][%d][%d] = \"%s\"\n",c3,c2,c1,sResult);
        n=0;
    }
    switch(lvl){
        case 3:
            c3++;
            c2=c1=0;
            break;
        case 2:
            c2++;
            c1=0;
            break;
        case 1:
            c1++;
    }

    return ;
}

void addChar(char c){
    sResult[n]=c;
    n++;
    sResult[n]=c=0;
}
/*______________________________________________________________________
*/

int main(){
    char buff[]= "0,1,2,4444444444;5,6,7,8888888888;.9,10,11,12121212;.";
    PrintLevel(0);
    char *p=buff;
    char c;
    int ret;
    int lvl;
    while(c=*p){

        lvl=(c==',')?1:((c==';')?2:((c=='.')?3:0) );

        if(lvl)
            PrintLevel(lvl);
        else
            addChar(c);
        p++;
    }
    PrintLevel(lvl);

}
```

Comment: This does not put the `int`s in an array.

Comment: @JonathanMee the heavy work is already done though, i got it working after some tweaking, i'll have the post updated with my code that takes care of this part.

Answer (score 0):

First note that a `long` is too small to hold even: `4444444444` [It's max size is: `2147483647`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx)

If a `long long` is used however the string can be eloquently parsed by a [`regex_token_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator). The parsing function should take in the input `string` and the delimiter and return separated `strings`. These inputs enable reuse in a function similar to this one:

```
auto parse(const string& input, const string& delimiter) {
    const regex re("([^" + delimiter + "]+)" + delimiter + '?');

    return vector<string>(sregex_token_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), re, 1), sregex_token_iterator());
}
```

This will return the `input` in a partitioned `vector<string>`. This return can then be partitioned until the third dimension in which each partition will contain only numeric characters. At that point [`stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) can be used to convert the `string` to a `long long`. This partitioning can be accomplished in nested loops like this:

```
vector<vector<vector<long long>>> foo;

for (auto& i : parse(str, "\\.")) {
    foo.resize(foo.size() + 1);
    for (auto& j : parse(i, ";")) {
        foo.back().resize(foo.back().size() + 1);
        for (auto& k : parse(j, ",")) {
            foo.back().back().push_back(stoll(k));
        }
    }
}
```

One key aspect of this is that each partition must contain a number. This is enforced by the `'+'` in `re` which will not match if consecutive delimiters occur. `stoll` is very robust and will eat whitespace if that is in the input `string`, however if a `string` containing only whitespace or generally does not contain a number is fed to it it will throw an error. If that is a concern be sure to check your inputs before calling `stoll`.

You can see a live example of this here: http://ideone.com/4vjdBx

Comment: you are right about 4444444444 and larger, these digits represent a unix timestamp actually (1445303228 for example), so they are in the range of long, my bad with the dummy string.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you saved the last post, this is an update to the last one, it handle 2D arrays as requested. hope you find it useful, if so send me a postcard :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


/*__________________________________________________________________________
*/

struct DATA{
   char a;
   char b;
   char c;
   unsigned long d;
};


/*__________________________________________________________________________

  allocate DATA struct, and fill it.
  on error or no data, returns NULL
*/
struct DATA *ParseString(char **pstr){
    int val=0;
    char *p;
    struct DATA *data;
    if(!pstr) return NULL;

    char *str=*pstr;
    if(!str) return NULL;

    // can be ommited
    // skipping non digital chars
    while(*str && !isdigit(*str))
        str++;

    //no digits?
    if(!*str) return NULL;

    p=str;
    //ok at least one
    data=(struct DATA*) calloc(1,sizeof(struct DATA));//calloc to initialize all to 0
    for(int n=0;n<4;n++){
        val=0;
        while(isdigit(*p)){
            val*=10;
            val+=(*p)-'0';
            p++;
        }
        switch(n){
            case 0:
                data->a=val;
                break;
            case 1:
                data->b=val;
                break;
            case 2:
                data->c=val;
                break;
            case 3:
                data->d=val;
                break;
        }
        val=0;
        if(*p!=',')
            break;
        p++;

    }
    *pstr=p;
    return data;
}
/*__________________________________________________________________________

    calculate the size of DATA * arra[c1][c2]
*/
void countArrBoudaries(char *s,unsigned short *c1,unsigned short *c2){
    *c1=*c2=0;
    unsigned short _c1=0;
    while(*s){
        switch(*s){
            case ';':
                _c1++;
                break;
            case '.':
                if(_c1>*c1)
                    *c1=_c1;
                _c1=0;
                *c2+=1;
                break;
        }
        s++;
    }
}
/*__________________________________________________________________________
*/
int main(void){

    struct DATA **pdata,*data;
    char buff[]="1,2,3,1445303228;4,5,6,1445303228;.7,8,9,1445303273;.";
    char *p=buff;
    unsigned short c1,c2;
    countArrBoudaries(buff,&c1,&c2);
    pdata=(struct DATA**)calloc((c2*c1),sizeof(pdata));

    if(pdata){
        // loading
        for(int i=0;i<c1;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<c2;j++)
                pdata[i+(j*c1)]=ParseString(&p);

        // printing:
        for(int i=0;i<c1;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<c2;j++){
                data=pdata[i+(j*c1)];
                if(data){
                    printf("data[%u][%u]={%d,%d,%d,%u};\n",i,j,data->a,data->b,data->c,data->d);
                }else{
                    printf("data[%u][%u]=NULL;\n",i,j);
                }
            }

        // freeing memory:
        for(int i=0;i<(c1*c2);i++)
            free(pdata[i]);
        free(pdata);

    }
    printf("\n\nDONE\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate further more? are you saying that i can have a struct as an array? how can i access all the elements? how about something like this `struct { int x, y; long d; } arr[4];`, `arr[0].x = 0; arr[3].y = 1;`, is this possible?

Comment: it works! i am mind-blown! for a 3D we can easily use `struct { int x = 0, y = 0; long t = 0; } arr[4][4]`;

Comment: i added an example ( source code) for demonstration purpose. please ensure that input string ends with a semicolon ";"

Comment: you even took it further with the dynamic memory allocation, which is essential in my case since i only have 8 kb to utilize. i really appreciate your input my friend. i had to use `data = (DATA *) calloc(nb, sizeof(DATA));` to get it running on my chip, the arduino ide is avr-gcc based.

Comment: i am trying to make it 2D now by taking "." into account, resulting an overall 3D structure `arr[i][j].a` along with the dynamic memory allocation, if this works it would be more than perfect. so far i am still having some difficulty implementing it, can you point me to a direction that can help me with this regard?

Comment: should i just add `case 3: data[i].d = atol(pp); break;` to have the long taking care of as well? will that be sufficient?

Comment: changing `sscanf(pp, "%u", &(data[i].d));` to `data[i].d = atol(pp);` did it for me. all set, except for the 2D part. i'll share my working code on a new answer, please have a look.

Comment: @user5470921 it is possible to make it 2D array, the data[1][1]  will be null then.

Comment: i mean how can we structure the array to be 2D and fill it with the appropriate values

Comment: it is little bit complicated than 1D array. i want to ask you. can this string array be longer? if so, how much items of  ";" in each "." ?

Comment: it is indeed more complicated, but it will make the usage of memory much better, hence a much better hardware performance. the string can be longer, we have to figure the size ourselves (we already did), the same with `;`s inside a `.`, we cannot tell, it can have as many as the string dictates, we have to extract that info ourselves that's why it's a little challenging, if we knew the sizes before then using a direct static array size def. would do it, but that's not the case, all dynamic here. the string can vary within the program (inside a loop), i am reading a live feed from a text file.

Comment: much much appreciated! i am getting a `'DATA' does not name a type` error from my compiler, once i work this out, it all should go very well. i'll let you know.

Comment: i guess that 'DATA' does not name a type  means that the compiler do not accept unnamed struct. i corrected this, it should go OK this time

Comment: same error i am afraid, still there, if you wish to test this out yourself, the compiler is available here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software.

Comment: i have internet issue, it is too slow, it will take a wile until i get the download

Comment: for some reason, it now works! even though hours ago it didn't, don't know why or how. hey man, if you were in my town, i'd buy you dinner, seriously, thank you.

Comment: alright, i know why, your last edit did it, i didn't notice it, you changed it two minutes exactly after i tested the last code.

Comment: can't, not enough rep., i will once it goes up.